# CUDA: new object in to global memory inside kernel

Tags: c++, c, cuda

Here's my code:

```
__global__ void myKernel(ComplexRTree *dev_rt) {
   dev_rt= new ComplexRTree();
}
class ComplexRTree { 
  ...
}

int main() {
   ComplexRTree *dev_rt;
   cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_rt, sizeof(ComplexRTree ));
   myKernel<<<1,1>>>(dev_rt);
}
```

So when I call `cudaMalloc`, `dev_rt` is allocated in *global memory*, but when I call `new` inside `myKernel`, is it still in global memory, or it was moved to *local memory* instead.

I'm so confused about this problem, all I want is allocated a complex RTree, which has dynamic size and might become very large (about 10,000,000 elements), to GPU memory. But when I use Cuda Debug in Nsight Visual Studio, it seem that use *local memory* and out of heap size. So I increase the heap size and it's worked, but I think that isn't what I want. Or maybe I misundertand something? Is there any way to `new` an complex class to *global memory*? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code makes little sense and doesn't illustrate your question at all. Where is  `dev_cc` defined?

Comment: sorry, it's `dev_rt`, i've edited

Comment: my problem is when I call `new` inside kernel: which memory `dev_rt` will be allocated? Local or global? All I want is allocated it in global memory, because of the limitation of the local memory

Comment: Why are you allocating `dev_rt` twice? And why  pass it by value to the kernel? Your core question is a duplicate and I have closed this as such, but your code is very confused

Comment: because I want to allocate it in GPU memory, I can use `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy` instead, but I try to find a way to call `new` to hope it will allocate directly into global memory.

Comment: I am afraid that makes no sense. Either allocate memory on the device runtime heap using `new`, or allocate memory with the host cudaMalloc APIs. Don't do both.